# Use extension for my certain View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have created a class used for an extension at my certain view controllers,

```
class STPopupTransitionAnimator: NSObject, STPopupControllerTransitioning {
....
}
```

and now I would like to set it to my View Controller, so I must not use the same code in my Home, profile, browse, search, etc like this:

```
extension HomeViewController: STPopupControllerTransitioning { 
    func popupControllerTransitionDuration(_ context: STPopupControllerTransitioningContext) -> TimeInterval {
        return context.action == .present ? 0.9 : 0.4
    }
}
```

The question is, how could I use my STPopupTransitionAnimator for my home, profile, and search view controller ?

What I don't want to do is to extend my UIViewController like this:

```
extension UIViewController: STPopupTransitionAnimator {}
```

because I only used that protocol only at certain view controllers and I used it to check it for something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a subclass of `UIViewController` like

```
class STPopupViewController: UIViewController, STPopupControllerTransitioning { 
    //all functions implementations 
}
```

and subclass your `UIViewControllers` from it

```
class HomeViewController: STPopupViewController { 

}
```

Comment: wow, i will try it tomorrow, and how to pass my variable from HomeViewController to my STPopupViewController ?

Comment: @calvinsugianto `HomeViewController` is `STPopupViewController`, everything, declared in `STPopupViewController` is available in `HomeViewController`, or you can override those functions to pass some other variable and then call `super.someFunction()`

Comment: oh, nice then, how about my UITableViewcontroller ? if i extends my UITAbleViewController from STPopupTransitionAnimator, i can't access self.tableView, it is almost done here

Comment: you can try subclassing `STPopupViewController: UITableViewController`

Comment: yes, i can extends it from UITableViewController, but i cant use it for UIViewController right? because i can choose only one

Comment: Yes, you have to choose one, actually there are no benefits of using table view controller instead of uiviewcontroller with tableview

Comment: ok, nice then, so i should change all of my UITableViewController to UIViewcontroller to conform my custom class, thanks